# putting message in dropdownlist in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, dropdown

I am calling an `API` and output of that `API` I am putting on the dropdown list.

[image]

These are the `country code` in my drop down list. I want to put default message in `drop down like`.
"Please select the country code" once user click then he can select countrycode. here by default EF is selected. in place of `EF` I want to put message.

Below `output` I am putting on the `list`.

```
 componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/country_code`).then((res) => {
      const countryData = res.data;
      this.setState({ countryData });
      alert(countryData);
    });
  }
```

`dropdown` code

```
 <select
            name="countriesValue"
            value={this.state.countriesValue}
            onChange={this.selectCountryCode}
          >
            {this.state.countryData.map((countryData) => (
              <option key={countryData} value={countryData}>
                {countryData}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
```

method:-

```
  selectCountryCode(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ countriesValue: e.target.value });
  }
```

`state` variable

```
this.state = {
      countryCode: '',
      countryData: [],
      countriesValue: '',
    };
```

what mistake I am doing in my `select`

Edit1:-

```
<select
            name="countriesValue"
            value={this.state.countriesValue}
            onChange={this.selectCountryCode}
          >
            <option value="" selected disabled hidden>
              Please select the country code
            </option>
            {this.state.countryData.map((countryData) => (
              <option key={countryData} value={countryData}>
                {countryData}
              </option>
            ))}

          </select>
```

After including this line

```
<option value="" selected disabled hidden>
              Please select the country code </option>
```

once user select the dropdown this `Please select the country code` does not appear again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a default value to the `<select>` element, you can add a disabled and hidden option like the following:

```
<select
 name="countriesValue"
 value={this.state.countriesValue}
 onChange={this.selectCountryCode}
>
 <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Please select the country code</option>
 {this.state.countryData.map((countryData) => (
   <option key={countryData} value={countryData}>
     {countryData}
   </option>
 ))}
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you Arjun

Comment: Hi Arjun once user select any value in dropdown then "Please select the country code" disappears. I have edited the question

Comment: Remove the `hidden` property for it to show. Remove the `disabled` property for it to be selectable. `<option value="" selected>Please select the country code</option>`